# How to invoke pardiso function in mex file when using gfortran compiler

Tags: matlab, gfortran, mex, intel-mkl

I'm trying to invoke `Parsido` function in `mex` file using gfortran compiler on `Linux` system. I use following instruction to compile:

```
mex '-I ${EBROOTIMKL}/mkl/include'...,
    '-L ${EBROOTIMKL}/mkl/lib'...,
    -lmkl_rt...,
    pardiso_sym_f90.f90 ero_dep_fortran.F -output ero_dep_fortran
```

I can successfully compile the `mex` file, but when I excute, `Matlab` crashes without any error information. I know it might be due to the use of `-lmkl_rt`, which might conflict with the `Intel iomp5` implementation of `OpenMP` which `MATLAB` uses.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: When matlab calls a mex file it call an external software and waits until its finished, so I doubt its a conflict. But chases generally are due to runtime errors in the code. Your function likely has a bug

Comment: @ Ander Biguri thanks for reply. Actually, I can run the mex file successfully on my laptop using intel fortran. So, I donot think there is any bug in the code.